# Dialogo en consola al usar mongoose-pagination

Tags: nodejs, consola

Estoy usando mongoose-pagination en una función de un controlador para un método get de mi api que me devuelva los documentos paginados de la colección. Al hacer la solicitud al api, en la consola me aparece el siguiente dialogo:

> "(node:13128) DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use Collection.countDocuments or Collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead"

No ha afectado al funcionamiento de mi api, pues el resultado es el esperado, sin embargo, quiero saber a que se debe este dialogo y si debo de corregir mi código para evitar futuros problemas. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
function getUsers(req,res){
var page = 1;
var itemsPerPage = 5;

/*obtener no. de pagina*/
if(req.params.page){
    page = req.params.page;
}

UserModel.find().sort('_id').paginate(page,itemsPerPage,(err,users,total)=>{
    if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});

    if(!users) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No hay usuarios disponibles'});

    return res.status(200).send({
        users,
        total,
        pages: Math.ceil(total/itemsPerPage)
    });
});}
```

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Sí, porque el módulo `mongoose-pagination` está usando el método obsoleto `Collection.count`: https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate/blob/d06a7d43ac2c404ef522e7cdc52d3de5eebd52e3/index.js#L54

Ese modúlo no se maniene. Podrias cambiarlo con otro módulo. Por ejemplo, con https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-paginate-v2.

Puedes ver que está usando el nuevo método `Collection.countDocuments`:

https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-paginate-v2/blob/5486f58a23f1ac42eeab08af2423609768edac90/src/index.js#L111-L115

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!

Como mencionaron, `moongose-pagination` usa el método `Collection.count` el cual es obsoleto. en su lugar usé `moongose-paginate-v2`. Dejaré mi código por si a alguien más le sirve de referencia.

Primero el esquema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginatev2 = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//definir esquema
var UserSchema = Schema({
    nombre: String,
    password: String,
    tel: String,
    cel: String,
});

//activar paginado
UserSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginatev2);

//exportar modulo
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UsuarioSchema);
```

Luego en el controlador:

```
//paginar usuarios
function getUsers(req,res){
var page = 1;

/*aquí podemos cambiar el nombre de las respuestas que serán devueltas
donde "totalDocs" cambió a "total" y así respectivamente*/
const CustomItems = {
    totalDocs: 'total',
    docs: 'usuarios',
    limit: 'perPage',
    page: 'page',
    totalPages: 'pages',
  };

//definir opciones de petición
const options = {page: page, limit: "límite-de-documetos-devueltos", sort:'_id', customLabels: CustomItems};

//paginar datos
UserModel.paginate({},options,(err,users)=>{
    if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});

    if(!users) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No hay usuarios disponibles'});

    return res.status(200).send({users});
});
```

}